# two methods that perform identical function, which is preferred? Is there an better alternative to both of them?

Tags: java, boolean

I have two version of a method that both perform the same function. They both tries to generate a random 6 digit number (which is converted to `String uuid`) and check if it unique by comparing it to an list of users' uuid (not shown here). It will keep going until the number generated is unique.

Because I'm still a beginner at java, so I was just wondering which version is more correct? Also, is there a better alternative to both of these methods?

```
String getNewUserUUID(){

    //inits
    String uuid = "";
    Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
    int length = 6;
    boolean unique;

    //continue looping until we get a unique ID
    do {
        unique = false;
        //generate number
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            uuid += randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10);
        }

        //check to make sure it's unique
        for(User u : users){
            if(uuid.compareTo(u.getUUID()) != 0){
                unique = true;
            }
        }
    } while (!unique);

    return uuid;
}


//version 2
String getNewUserUUID(){

    //inits
    String uuid = "";
    Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
    int length = 6;

    boolean nonUnique;

    do {
        //generate the uuid
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            uuid += randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10);
        }

        //check to make sure it's unique
        nonUnique = false;
        for(User u : this.users){
            if(uuid.compareTo(u.getUUID()) == 0){
                nonUnique = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    } while (nonUnique);

    return uuid;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `java.util.UUID` or various 3rd party libraries that create UUIDs.

They will produce a UUID using various pieces of info so that it can be known to be unique when created, without having to do the "pick some random stuff, check that against all my other UUIDs and see if there's a repeat" loop you are doing.

Is having a 6-digit UUID a requirement, or are you just using that as an example?

If your UUIDs really are 6 numeric digits, then perhaps initialize a `java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger` to 100000 and have your generate UUID method just return what `AtomicInteger.getAndIncrement()` returns (I'm leaving out any error checking -- if your UUIDs are exactly 6 digits then obviously you'll need to do some checking and take whatever action is appropriate when you get to 999999):

```
final public class PoorMansUuid
{
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(100000);

    public static int generateUuid() {
        return counter.getAndIncrement();
    }
}
```

Comment: oh wow, didnt know such library existed. Thank you so much for the suggestion, will definitly help me a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no single "correct" way. But if you're looking for alternatives, here's one that's a bit simpler and more efficient, IMO:

```
String getNewUserUUID(){

    //inits
    Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();
    final int length = 6;

    //continue looping until we get a unique ID
    while (true) {
        //generate number
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);
        for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            sb.append(randomNumberGenerator.nextInt(10));
        }
        String uuid = sb.toString();

        //check to make sure it's unique
        for(User u : users){
            if(uuid.equals(u.getUUID())){
                continue;
            }
        }

        return uuid;
    }
}
```